# Thinking in Java 4th Edition (trying to build the project of the book using NetBeans without success)

Tags: java, netbeans

After downloading the code required for the book, I extracted the file in C: and whenever I try to open the project in NetBeans it doesn't read the file as a project. It sees it as a normal file.

I found a similar question asked about Eclipse, and the answer wasn't clear. I'm hoping I can get a step by step beginner friendly answer.

Thanks.

**Edit:** I'm using NetBeans IDE 8.2, the code I downloaded was from this link: https://github.com/BruceEckel/TIJ4-code

I simply clicked File -> Open project -> unzipped file
This is how I typically open any project I download.

Comment: Where did you download that project(s) from? What is your NetBeans version? What steps precisely did you take to open the project?

Comment: please clarify the exact issue you are facing.. also in netbeans, try to import the project\

Comment: post the code to github and let us have a look

Comment: Updated the question hopefully this information is useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IDE's have project files which are different from language files such as java or c.

You can probably just create a new project and then pull that java file into the project through copy-paste or moving it through your computer's directory.

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work. It made things much more messy. Someone mentioned something about Maven in the other question about Eclipse, I don't know if this is relevant or not.